# getting error when try to build production with ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps, ionic-native

I am getting error when try to build production for the pwa in ionic.

i have attach screenshot of error, ionic and npm version configuration, and also app module file.

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please avoid Using Images in your Question. Post your Code instead of Images. Please Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
Update your Question with More details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this **import { BackgroundGeolocation} from '@ionic-native/background-geolocation/ngx'** instead of **import BackgroundGeolocation from 'cordova-background-geolocation-lt'** and try again.